# Reference assembly could not be loaded

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui, assembly-references

I keep getting this error when I build a MAUI proj in visual studio. Any one can help?

ILLink : error IL1039: Reference assembly '***.dll***' could not be loaded.

Comment: Could you provide some more info about this error? BTW, you can try to remove .bin folder manually and then rebuild your application.